# Absolutely positioned text in flexbox causes extra width to be added

Tags: css, flexbox

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpqegQ

html

```
<div class="flex1">
  <div class="flex2">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div class="zero">
      <span>Zero Text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.flex1 {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  width: 300px;
}

.flex2 {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: 3px solid #00cc00;
}

.flex2 > div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid #cc0000;
  text-align: center;  
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.flex2 > .zero {
  width: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.flex2 > .zero > span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  top: 20px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

I'm in a situation where a zero-width element that contains an absolutely positioned element that's wider than its zero-width container that is on the edge of another container with `overflow-x: scroll` causes extra width to be added to the parent. Whew, what a sentence.

The outer container `flex1` is 300px wide, is `display: flex`, and has `overflow-x: scroll`.

`flex2` is also `display: flex`, and has `margin-left: auto` to align `flex2` to the right inside `flex`.

`flex2` correctly aligns to the right side of its container.

The problem is that the last child of `flex2` is zero-width. It contains an absolutely positioned element that is wider. This then causes `flex1` to display the scrollbar.

Is this expected and/or is there a way to fix it without adding `overflow: hidden` to `flex2`?

Comment: This is expected behavior and will need `overflow: hidden` to prevent it from happen

Comment: Yeah, it's expected, not specific to flexbox either. Here's the same thing with a float http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWvKLX or with inline-block http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWvKLX There may be another solution, but it would probably depend on your end goal. What are you trying to do with the `.zero` element being `width: 0` and having content in it that you want to display? And I'm assuming you want to hide some of it's overflow but not all of it? Why don't you want to use `overflow: hidden` on `.flex2`?

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thanks for clearing that up. There's position absolute content in the actual implementation that needs to be visible outside of `flex2`. Negated the ability to use `overflow: hidden`. Ended up adding a selector for only the condition when `.zero:last-child` that adds enough margin right to push the content back left.

Comment: Are you constrained to the given markup structure? ... and by simply remove `overflow-x: scroll` the scroll disappears.